# What is required to format a document with alternating margins?

Tags: margins, double-sided

What is exactly the command or the document class which is required to format a document such that it has alternating margins? Default values for margin space which are appropriate for dissertations are desired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the `book` or `report` class or the koma script variants `scrbook` and `scrreprt` then you should have alternating margins by default. It is enabled using the `twoside` class option and disabled using the `oneside` option.

If you want to change the margins then you can do this e.g. using the `geometry` package. It accepts the `margin=<length>` option for all sides or `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` for the separate margins. The koma script classes have their own margin settings. See its manual for the details.